# Some VMs starting up after cold boot, unsolicited ?

Tags: vmware-esxi, high-availability, vmware-vsphere

I 've got a small lab set up with trial ESXi 4.x with latest updates and patches.
On the moment I 'm testing HA with some strange results.
As mentioned above some VMs start up without having configured to do so.

1. At the host configuration tab, virtual machine startup/shutdown, I 'v only marked vCenter to automatically start up
2. Cluster features

   - Turn on VMware HA
3. VMware HA

   - Enable Host minitoring
4. Virtual machine options

   - VM restart priotity: low/high
   - Host isolation response: shutdown
5. VM monitoring

   - Enable VM monitoring
     Virtual machine settings
   - VM monitoring: low/medium

The stupid thing is that other VMs with the same settings do NOT start up.
All VM's were shutdown properly.

Any ideas?

Greetz Jaap

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well my answer applies, but at my company we use ESX and virtual center to manage. When I log into Virtual Center I look at our ESX server settings, not the settings of the individual servers. We have 5 ESX servers in a clustered environment, so I'm just looking at one of those 5.

I click on the configuration tab, then "Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown". I have seen this option before in other versions of VMWare, so I bet you have it too somewhere. Once in there you can edit the properties of this item and choose how servers startup/shutdown. We set all of our servers to "Any Order" except the absolute critical ones, those are ordered, but we only order a select few.

Hope this helps...